# python read seperated tsv file into multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, io

I have some data in text file that I want to read into a dictionary of multiple pandas dataframes as values. The file looks like this:

```
Name    id    chr    start    end    coverage
> Gene : 1
source  0       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       3652523 3652641 22.1891
2       2       1       3682333 3682430 49.6224
3       3       1       3683060 3683180 43.2893
4       4       1       3698053 3698151 1.35354
5       5       1       3707549 3707791 55.2881
6       6       1       3722021 3722207 55.107
tank    16      1       0       0       0
> Gene : 2
source  0       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       9292888 9293071 15.288
2       2       1       9355743 9356585 36.3796
3       3       1       9367448 9369525 26.6434
tank    4       1       0       0       0
> Gene : 3
source  0       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       54779719        54781779        2.131
2       2       1       54782325        54782477        3.08497
3       3       1       54785983        54786144        4.00617
4       4       1       54786521        54786956        0.688073
5       5       1       54786957        54787075        4.32773
6       6       1       54787711        54787826        2.91379
7       7       1       54788042        54788097        2.16071
8       8       1       54800597        54801260        2.61596
tank    9       1       0       0       0
```

I would like to have a dictionary with the gene id (1,2,3,...) as key and the lines until the next gene id as the corresponding value in a pandas dataframe.

Any tips on how to easily solve that?

Comment: process it as normal text - read line by line and keep lines on list and save them to one file when you get line with `> Gene:` - and then start again - clear list, read line by line, keep on list, and when there will be another `> Gene:` then save it new file, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Process it as normal text. Use `split("> Gene :")` and you will have every part in separted string. In first string you will have `headers` and in others you will have `data` with `number` in first line. And if you split it on first `\n` then you will have separated `number` and `data.

And then you can convert to `DataFrame` without saving on disk

```
text = headers + data
df = pd.read_csv( io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')
```

Minimal working example with data directly in code

```
text = '''Name    id    chr    start    end    coverage
> Gene : 1
source  0       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       3652523 3652641 22.1891
2       2       1       3682333 3682430 49.6224
3       3       1       3683060 3683180 43.2893
4       4       1       3698053 3698151 1.35354
5       5       1       3707549 3707791 55.2881
6       6       1       3722021 3722207 55.107
tank    16      1       0       0       0
> Gene : 2
source  0       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       9292888 9293071 15.288
2       2       1       9355743 9356585 36.3796
3       3       1       9367448 9369525 26.6434
tank    4       1       0       0       0
> Gene : 3
source  0       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       54779719        54781779        2.131
2       2       1       54782325        54782477        3.08497
3       3       1       54785983        54786144        4.00617
4       4       1       54786521        54786956        0.688073
5       5       1       54786957        54787075        4.32773
6       6       1       54787711        54787826        2.91379
7       7       1       54788042        54788097        2.16071
8       8       1       54800597        54801260        2.61596
tank    9       1       0       0       0'''

import pandas as pd
import io

#text = open(filename).read()

parts = text.split('> Gene : ')

headers = parts[0]

all_data = {}

for part in parts[1:]: # skip headers

    # split on first `\n` to get number and data
    number, data = part.split('\n', 1)
    number = int(number)
    
    # convert to DataFrame and add to dictionary
    text = headers + data
    all_data[number] = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')
    
    # display it
    print('---')
    print('number:', number)
    print(all_data[number])
```

Result

```
-----
number: 1
     Name  id  chr    start      end  coverage
0  source   0    1        0        0   0.00000
1       1   1    1  3652523  3652641  22.18910
2       2   2    1  3682333  3682430  49.62240
3       3   3    1  3683060  3683180  43.28930
4       4   4    1  3698053  3698151   1.35354
5       5   5    1  3707549  3707791  55.28810
6       6   6    1  3722021  3722207  55.10700
7    tank  16    1        0        0   0.00000
-----
number: 2
     Name  id  chr    start      end  coverage
0  source   0    1        0        0    0.0000
1       1   1    1  9292888  9293071   15.2880
2       2   2    1  9355743  9356585   36.3796
3       3   3    1  9367448  9369525   26.6434
4    tank   4    1        0        0    0.0000
-----
number: 3
     Name  id  chr     start       end  coverage
0  source   0    1         0         0  0.000000
1       1   1    1  54779719  54781779  2.131000
2       2   2    1  54782325  54782477  3.084970
3       3   3    1  54785983  54786144  4.006170
4       4   4    1  54786521  54786956  0.688073
5       5   5    1  54786957  54787075  4.327730
6       6   6    1  54787711  54787826  2.913790
7       7   7    1  54788042  54788097  2.160710
8       8   8    1  54800597  54801260  2.615960
9    tank   9    1         0         0  0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach

- get each row as text into a DataFrame
- find rows that contain breaks
- insert into `dict` a dataframe for rows between each of the breaks

```
import io
# create DF that is just raw text for each line in input
df = pd.DataFrame("""Name    id    chr    start    end    coverage
> Gene : 1
source  0       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       3652523 3652641 22.1891
2       2       1       3682333 3682430 49.6224
3       3       1       3683060 3683180 43.2893
4       4       1       3698053 3698151 1.35354
5       5       1       3707549 3707791 55.2881
6       6       1       3722021 3722207 55.107
tank    16      1       0       0       0
> Gene : 2
source  0       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       9292888 9293071 15.288
2       2       1       9355743 9356585 36.3796
3       3       1       9367448 9369525 26.6434
tank    4       1       0       0       0
> Gene : 3
source  0       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       54779719        54781779        2.131
2       2       1       54782325        54782477        3.08497
3       3       1       54785983        54786144        4.00617
4       4       1       54786521        54786956        0.688073
5       5       1       54786957        54787075        4.32773
6       6       1       54787711        54787826        2.91379
7       7       1       54788042        54788097        2.16071
8       8       1       54800597        54801260        2.61596
tank    9       1       0       0       0""".split("\n"),  columns=["raw"])
# find rows that are genes
bri = df[df["raw"].str.contains("> Gene :")].index
bri

dfs = {}
# insert into dict rows between each gene
for i, r in enumerate(bri):
    endrow=len(df) if i==(len(bri)-1) else bri[i+1]-1
    # NB used space delimiter not tab as pasted from SO
    dfs[df.loc[r]["raw"]] = \
        pd.DataFrame(df.loc[r+1:endrow]["raw"].str.split(r"[ ]+").tolist(),
                 columns=df.loc[0].str.split(r"[ ]+").tolist()
                )

dfs
```

### output

```
{'> Gene : 1':      Name  id chr    start      end coverage
 0  source   0   1        0        0        0
 1       1   1   1  3652523  3652641  22.1891
 2       2   2   1  3682333  3682430  49.6224
 3       3   3   1  3683060  3683180  43.2893
 4       4   4   1  3698053  3698151  1.35354
 5       5   5   1  3707549  3707791  55.2881
 6       6   6   1  3722021  3722207   55.107
 7    tank  16   1        0        0        0,
 '> Gene : 2':      Name id chr    start      end coverage
 0  source  0   1        0        0        0
 1       1  1   1  9292888  9293071   15.288
 2       2  2   1  9355743  9356585  36.3796
 3       3  3   1  9367448  9369525  26.6434
 4    tank  4   1        0        0        0,
 '> Gene : 3':      Name id chr     start       end  coverage
 0  source  0   1         0         0         0
 1       1  1   1  54779719  54781779     2.131
 2       2  2   1  54782325  54782477   3.08497
 3       3  3   1  54785983  54786144   4.00617
 4       4  4   1  54786521  54786956  0.688073
 5       5  5   1  54786957  54787075   4.32773
 6       6  6   1  54787711  54787826   2.91379
 7       7  7   1  54788042  54788097   2.16071
 8       8  8   1  54800597  54801260   2.61596
 9    tank  9   1         0         0         0}
```